# I want to prove completeness of $C[a,b]$ with metric induced by max norm, but need help

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I added a picture, please check it.

Can someone please explain the last three line of the proof?

I thought by finding a cauchy sequence that converges to a continuous function we are done with proving completeness of $C[a,b]$ with metric induced by max norm. Why did they add the last three lines "highlighted" and how do I prove them? Please, help, thanks.

[image]

Comment: They added the last three highlighted lines because before of them they only proved the theorem in the particular case that $(2)$ holds and so it was necessary to add the last three lines in order to prove the theorem in the general case.

Comment: I always use the straightforward proof here: $(f_n(x))_n$ is also Cauchy in $\Bbb R$ so converges to a unique number we call $f(x)$, and then show $f$ is continuous, so it's in $C[a,b]$, and finally that $\| f_n -f\|\to 0$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence of elements of $C[a,b]$. There is a $N_1\in\Bbb N$ such that$$m,n\geqslant N_1\implies\|f_m-f_n\|_\max<1.$$And there is a $N_2\in\Bbb N$ such that$$m,n\geqslant N_2\implies\|f_m-f_n\|_\max<\frac12.$$You can assume, without loss of generality, that $N_2>N_1$. Now, there is a $N_3\in\Bbb N$ such that$$m,n\geqslant N_3\implies\|f_m-f_n\|_\max<\frac1{2^2}$$and you can assume, without loss of generality, that $N_3>N_2$. But then $(f_{N_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence of $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and$$(\forall k\in\Bbb N):\left\|f_{N_{k+1}}-f_{N_k}\right\|<\frac1{2^{k-1}}.$$So, by the first part of the proof, $\left(f_{N_k}\right)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly. In particular, the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence. But then $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$  itself is convergent, since, as the author remarks, in order to prove that a Cauchy sequence converges it is enough to prove that it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: thank you, so this basically shows that every cauchy sequenece has a subsequence in which inequality 2 holds right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And, since a Cauchy sequence converges if and only if it has a convergent subsequence, you're done.

Comment: why and how did we start with 1 then 1/2 then 1/2^k-1

Comment: I chose the sequence $\left(\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ because the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^{n-1}}$ converges.

Comment: but how do we get the last inequality (from a sequence form to a subsequesnce)?

Comment: Which inequality? Is it$$(\forall k\in\Bbb N):\left\|f_{N_{k+1}}-f_{N_k}\right\|<\frac1{2^{k-1}}?$$

Comment: yes how did we end up getting it where did the sub k+1 and k came from

Comment: There is some $N_1$ such that$$m,n\geqslant N_1\implies\|f_m-f_n\|_\max<1$$and there is a $N_2\in\Bbb N$ such that$$m,n\geqslant N_2\implies\|f_m-f_n\|_\max<\frac12.$$In particular,$$\|f_{N_2}-f_{N_1}\|_\max<1,$$since $N_1,N_2\geqslant N_1$. And there is a $N_3\in\Bbb N$ such that$$m,n\geqslant N_3\implies\|f_m-f_n\|_\max<\frac1{2^2}.$$In particular,$$\|f_{N_3}-f_{N_2}\|_\max<\frac12,$$since $N_2,N_3\geqslant N_2$. And so on.

Comment: Thank you so much I deeply appreciate it. I tried postion another question but its not working can I aske you here? Find a metric on Rn that is not equivalent to p(x,y)=|x1+x2|+....|xn+yn| and p*=max{|x1+x2|+....|xn+yn| } where wo metrics p and o- on a set X are said to be equivalent provided there are positive
numbers cl and c2 such that for all x1, x2 E X,
cl.d(xl,x2)< P(x1,x2)<c2d(xl,x2) I think its the discrete mertic but can you please show me how in details

Comment: The comments are not meant to post new questions. And if my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: sorry im new to this platform, is there any way that i can reach you, they wont let me post another question

Comment: I do not want to be contacted outside MathStackExchange due to something related to MathStackExchange. When you will became able to post questions again, I will try to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

The proof begins with a particular case: it assumes that the norm $$\|f_{n+k}-f_{k}\|_{\infty}\leq a_{k}$$ is controlled by $a_{k}$ real number which is the addend of a converging sum $\sum_{k}a_{k}$. The last $3$ lines are telling you how to adapt the particular case to the general one.

Comment: And note that the first comment in yellow should say **subsequence** at the end. It's an error in the text.

Comment: @henno thank you yes as you said its supposed to be subsequence spelling error...but can you please help me with proving last 3 lines

Comment: @Davide please help with full proof